# In WinUI 3, is there a way to dynamically set a Window's size and position?

Tags: c#, .net-core, winui-3

In .NET WinUI 3 (`Microsoft.UI.Xaml.*` in Windows 11), I am looking for a way to dynamically set my main Window's initial size and position.

Ideally, I would like to:

- Detect which of the `1..*` monitors has the focus when the app is launched. (Or at least default to the primary display.)
- Open my main Window on that screen, at coordinates `0, 0`.
- Set my main Window's dimensions to occupy 100% of that screen's client area. (eg, Minus the taskbar, if applicable. I don't mean full-screen or maximized. Just an ordinary floating window that occupies 100% of the usable area and doesn't run off the edges.)

However, it doesn't appear that `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window` has any constructor, property, or method to set its size and position. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window)

Is there a new-paradigm way to do this? Or is it just a use case that WinUI 3 considers irrelevant?

Thanks.

Comment: `Windows.UI.Xaml` is *not* WinUI3, it's UWP. WinUI3 is located in `Microsoft.UI.Xaml`. Yes it's super confusing :-) I suggest you read this excellent article https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/05/what-is-actually-the-universal-windows-platform-and-what-is-winui-msix-and-project-reunion/ that should clear things up for you. With WinUI3, you can use the associated `AppWindow` class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/windowing/windowing-overview to change size and position

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier ! Care to convert this to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Windows.UI.Xaml` is not a WinUI3 namespace, it's a UWP namespace (sometimes called "WUX").

WinUI3's XAML namespace is `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` (sometimes called "MUX").

<rant>Everyone (except Microsoft I guess) agrees that all these names, including "WinUI3" itself (a summit in marketing naming matter, while inferior to the brilliant "Windows App SDK") which is very different than WinUI2 and/or UWP while "similar", is super confusing and the official doc (while still under improvement) does not always help in that matter...<rant>

I suggest you read this excellent article [What is Actually the Universal Windows Platform and what is WinUI, MSIX, and Project Reunion / Windows App SDK?](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/05/what-is-actually-the-universal-windows-platform-and-what-is-winui-msix-and-project-reunion/) that should hopefully clear things up a bit.

So, back to WinUI3, you can simply use the associated [AppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/windowing/windowing-overview) classto change size and position:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ...

    this.AppWindow.MoveAndResize(new Windows.Graphics.RectInt32(100, 100, 100, 100));
}
```